# authlogic validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

Sorry for stupid question. but do I need to use standart model validation, such as

```
validates_length_of :login, :maxinum => 25
```

if I use authlogic  validation:

```
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.validates_length_of_login_field_options = {:within => 2..25}
  end
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't. That's what Authlogic's methods are for.